# Let $I,J $ ideals of $R$ is $(IJ)[X] = I[X]J[X]$ true?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, ring-theory, ideals

Let $I,J $ ideals of $R$ is $(IJ)[X] = I[X]J[X]$ true?

Attempt: The inclusion $\supseteq$ is obvious. For the other inclusion, take $f \in (IJ)[X]$. Then we can write $f$ as a sum of polynomials of the form

$$ijX^k$$ where $k \geq 0, i \in I, j \in J$. But

$$ijX^k = i(jX^k) \in i J[X] \subseteq I[X]J[X]$$

and thus $f \in I[X]J[X]$ as well.

Is this correct? (just need a quick sanity check).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.

Also you may prove it in this way:
$$I \ \text{ Is Right Ideal } \ \Longrightarrow I[X]J[X] \subseteq (IJ)[X]$$
$$J \ \text{ Is Left Ideal } \ \Longrightarrow I[X]J[X] \subseteq (IJ)[X]$$